# Disconnected from the Server : Shiny

Tags: google-analytics, shiny, shiny-server

Hey everyone I am pretty new to shiny and I have managed to write two seperate files of code ui.R and server.R and that I did next is to run the app and then deploy it to the shiny server. But after some time when I close the source file and run it on the server using the web address a message shows up saying it is Disconnected from the server?

Am I missing something in this whole process? I managed to save the R Script as two separate files. Should I do something along with this. Need your help..

A little more info on what the App is all about... It is actually an automatic dashboard which fetches data from Google Analytics and shows up in this dashboard in the specified field

Comment: have a look in the log files of your app which are by default in `/var/log/shiny-server/your-app`

Comment: I guess the error is here  Error : Refresh token not available

Comment: It is a Google Analytics API error, as I can see from a rough internet search